# How to make use of a free SSL certificate?

Tags: networking, ssl, certificate

I'm using Network Solutions, who want me to give them $50 or $100 per year to have SSL protection with my hosting. I keep hearing about free SSL certificates though. Can I really use one of those with N.S.? I would think they'd try to block any such attempt. If they don't block it, how do I install it? Is it just a matter of ftp'ing the file in and updating .htaccess? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you can't just FTP a certificate into place and adjust the `.htaccess` file, if you're on shared hosting.

If you have root access to the hosting solution or full control over the entire webserver, you *can* just configure the webserver globally for SSL support and upload the certificate, including a free one.

The free certificates are good for providing encryption (i.e., for a login page), but aren't very good for authentication (proving you are who you say you are). If you're running a business and people need to know that they're talking to *you* and not someone pretending to be *you*, then you should look at the $50-$100 options, as those typically come with higher assurances.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in

https://gethttpsforfree.com/

PS: I know it's a old topic, but i think a good idea let record of it.